# DocuSign API returning errorCode REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE

Tags: c#, docusignapi

When trying to send two 19MB documents in the envelope I am getting this error code `REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE`.

I developed in C# with binary transfer as suggested by DocuSign.

`SendEnvelope` main console code:

```cs
DocuSignLib.SendEnvelope sendEnvelope = new DocuSignLib.SendEnvelope();

// 19MB file 1
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Resources", "19MB.pdf");
sendEnvelope.AddDocument(filePath);

// 19MB file 2
filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Resources", "19MB_1.pdf");
sendEnvelope.AddDocument(filePath);

sendEnvelope.AddSigner(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SignerName"],
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SignerEmail"], "1", "*s1*", "*r1*", null, null, 20, 10);

var envSummary = sendEnvelope.Send(config.UserId,
    config.IntegrationKey,
    config.RSAPrivateKey,
    config.IsDeveloperSandbox,
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSubject"],
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailBody"],
    600);

Console.WriteLine("\tEnvelope Id: " + envSummary.EnvelopeId);
Console.WriteLine("\tEnvelope Status: " + envSummary.Status);
Console.WriteLine("\tEnvelope Uri: " + envSummary.Uri);

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

`SendEnvelope` class:

```cs
using DocuSign.eSign.Model;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

public class SendEnvelope
{
    private List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> signers = new List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();

    private List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> carbonCopies = new List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();

    List<dynamic> docs = new List<dynamic>();

    private List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> witnesses = new List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();

    private DocuSignConfig Config;

    public void AddSigner(string Name,
                          string Email,
                          string RecipientId,
                          string SignHereAnchor,
                          string InitialHereAnchor,
                          string EmailSubject,
                          string EmailBody,
                          int AnchorXOffset,
                          int AnchorYOffset)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RecipientId))
        {
            if (Util.IsValidEmail(Email))
            {
                Dictionary<string, dynamic> signer = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                    {
                        { "email", Email },
                        { "name", Name },
                        { "recipientId", RecipientId }
                    };

                Dictionary<string, dynamic> signHere = null;
                Dictionary<string, dynamic> initialHere = null;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SignHereAnchor))
                {
                    signHere = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                        {
                            { "anchorString", SignHereAnchor },
                            { "anchorYOffset", AnchorYOffset.ToString() },
                            { "anchorUnits", "pixels" },
                            { "anchorXOffset", AnchorXOffset.ToString() }
                        };
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InitialHereAnchor))
                {
                    initialHere = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                        {
                            { "anchorString", InitialHereAnchor },
                            { "anchorYOffset", AnchorYOffset.ToString() },
                            { "anchorUnits", "pixels" },
                            { "anchorXOffset", AnchorXOffset.ToString() }
                        };
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailSubject) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailBody))
                {
                    Dictionary<string, dynamic> emailNotification = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                        {
                            { "emailSubject", EmailSubject },
                            { "emailBody", EmailBody }
                        };

                    signer.Add("emailNotification", emailNotification);
                }

                if (initialHere != null || signHere != null)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, dynamic> Tabs = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                        {
                            { "initialHereTabs", new dynamic[] { initialHere } },
                            { "signHereTabs", new dynamic[] { signHere } }
                        };

                    signer.Add("tabs", Tabs);
                }

                signers.Add(signer);
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("The e-mail " + Email + " is ivalid!");
        }
    }

    public void AddCarbonCopy(string Name, string Email, string EmailSubject, string EmailBody)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email))
        {
            if (Util.IsValidEmail(Email))
            {
                Dictionary<string, dynamic> cc = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                    {
                        { "email", Email },
                        { "name", Name }
                    };

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailSubject) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailBody))
                {
                    Dictionary<string, dynamic> emailNotification = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                        {
                            { "emailSubject", EmailSubject },
                            { "emailBody", EmailBody }
                        };

                    cc.Add("emailNotification", emailNotification);
                }

                carbonCopies.Add(cc);
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("The e-mail " + Email + " is ivalid!");
        }
    }

    public void AddWitness(string Name,
                           string Email,
                           string RecipientId,
                           string WitnessFor, // Signer RecipentId
                           string SignHereAnchor,
                           string InitialHereAnchor,
                           string EmailSubject,
                           string EmailBody,
                           int AnchorXOffset,
                           int AnchorYOffset)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RecipientId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(WitnessFor))
        {
            if (Util.IsValidEmail(Email))
            {
                Dictionary<string, dynamic> wit = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                    {
                        { "email", Email },
                        { "name", Name },
                        { "recipientId", RecipientId },
                        { "witnessFor", WitnessFor }
                    };

                Dictionary<string, dynamic> signHere = null;
                Dictionary<string, dynamic> initialHere = null;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SignHereAnchor))
                {
                    signHere = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                        {
                            { "anchorString", SignHereAnchor },
                            { "anchorYOffset", AnchorYOffset.ToString() },
                            { "anchorUnits", "pixels" },
                            { "anchorXOffset", AnchorXOffset.ToString() }
                        };
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InitialHereAnchor))
                {
                    initialHere = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                        {
                            { "anchorString", InitialHereAnchor },
                            { "anchorYOffset", AnchorYOffset.ToString() },
                            { "anchorUnits", "pixels" },
                            { "anchorXOffset", AnchorXOffset.ToString() }
                        };
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailSubject) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailBody))
                {
                    Dictionary<string, dynamic> emailNotification = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                        {
                            { "emailSubject", EmailSubject },
                            { "emailBody", EmailBody }
                        };

                    wit.Add("emailNotification", emailNotification);
                }

                if (initialHere != null || signHere != null)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, dynamic> Tabs = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                        {
                            { "initialHereTabs", new dynamic[] { initialHere } },
                            { "signHereTabs", new dynamic[] { signHere } }
                        };

                    wit.Add("tabs", Tabs);
                }

                witnesses.Add(wit);
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("The e-mail " + Email + " is ivalid!");
        }
    }

    public void AddWitnessGroup(string GroupName,
                                string GroupId,
                                string RecipientId,
                                string WitnessFor, // Signer RecipentId
                                string SignHereAnchor,
                                string InitialHereAnchor,
                                string EmailSubject,
                                string EmailBody,
                                int AnchorXOffset,
                                int AnchorYOffset)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GroupName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(GroupId) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RecipientId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(WitnessFor))
        {
            Dictionary<string, dynamic> wit = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                    {
                        { "signingGroupId", GroupId },
                        { "signingGroupName", GroupName },
                        { "recipientId", RecipientId },
                        { "witnessFor", WitnessFor }
                    };

            Dictionary<string, dynamic> signHere = null;
            Dictionary<string, dynamic> initialHere = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SignHereAnchor))
            {
                signHere = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                        {
                            { "anchorString", SignHereAnchor },
                            { "anchorYOffset", AnchorYOffset.ToString() },
                            { "anchorUnits", "pixels" },
                            { "anchorXOffset", AnchorXOffset.ToString() }
                        };
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InitialHereAnchor))
            {
                initialHere = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                        {
                            { "anchorString", InitialHereAnchor },
                            { "anchorYOffset", AnchorYOffset.ToString() },
                            { "anchorUnits", "pixels" },
                            { "anchorXOffset", AnchorXOffset.ToString() }
                        };
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailSubject) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailBody))
            {
                Dictionary<string, dynamic> emailNotification = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                        {
                            { "emailSubject", EmailSubject },
                            { "emailBody", EmailBody }
                        };

                wit.Add("emailNotification", emailNotification);
            }

            if (initialHere != null || signHere != null)
            {
                Dictionary<string, dynamic> Tabs = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
                    {
                        { "initialHereTabs", new dynamic[] { initialHere } },
                        { "signHereTabs", new dynamic[] { signHere } }
                    };

                wit.Add("tabs", Tabs);
            }

            witnesses.Add(wit);
        }
    }

    private void ValidateFileExtension(string FileExtension)
    {
        if (!Util.IsValidFileExtension(FileExtension))
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid file extension '" + FileExtension + "'! DocuSign eSignature supports the following file types: " + Util.GetValidFileExtensions());
        }
    }

    public void AddDocument(string FileName, byte[] FileContent)
    {
        ValidateFileExtension(Path.GetExtension(FileName));

        docs.Add(
            new
            {
                mime = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(FileName),
                name = FileName,
                documentId = (docs.Count + 1).ToString(),
                bytes = FileContent
            });
    }

    public void AddDocument(string FilePath)
    {
        ValidateFileExtension(Path.GetExtension(FilePath));

        byte[] buff = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);

        if (buff != null)
        {
            docs.Add(
            new
            {
                mime = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(FilePath),
                name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FilePath),
                documentId = (docs.Count + 1).ToString(),
                bytes = buff
            });
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, dynamic> CreateEnvelope(string EmailSubject, string EmailBody)
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
            {
                { "emailSubject", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailSubject) ? EmailSubject : null},
                { "emailBlurb", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailBody) ? EmailBody : null},
                { "documents", docs.ToArray() },
                { "recipients", CreateRecipients() },
                { "status", "sent" }
            };
    }

    private Dictionary<string, dynamic> CreateRecipients()
    {
        // Order the recipients
        int order = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < signers.Count; i++)
        {
            signers[i]["routingOrder"] = order.ToString();
            order++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < witnesses.Count; i++)
        {
            witnesses[i]["routingOrder"] = order.ToString();
            order++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < carbonCopies.Count; i++)
        {
            carbonCopies[i]["routingOrder"] = order.ToString();
            order++;
        }

        return new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
            {
                { "signers", signers },
                { "carbonCopies", carbonCopies },
                { "witnesses", witnesses }
            };
    }

    public EnvelopeSummaryCopy Send(string UserId, string IntegrationKey, string RSAPrivateKey, bool IsDeveloperSandbox, string EmailSubject, string EmailBody, int ApiTimeout)
    {
        if (docs.Count == 0 || signers.Count == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailSubject))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("No {0} found!",
                docs.Count == 0 ? "document" : (signers.Count == 0 ? "signer" : "e-mail subject")));
        else
        {
            EnvelopeSummaryCopy esc;

            try
            {
                esc = SendNow(UserId, IntegrationKey, RSAPrivateKey, IsDeveloperSandbox, EmailSubject, EmailBody, ref ApiTimeout);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Token expired, try again
                if (ex.Message.Contains("USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED"))
                {
                    JWTAuth.ClearToken();

                    esc = SendNow(UserId, IntegrationKey, RSAPrivateKey, IsDeveloperSandbox, EmailSubject, EmailBody, ref ApiTimeout);
                }
                else
                    throw ex;
            }

            return esc;
        }
    }

    private EnvelopeSummaryCopy SendNow(string UserId, string IntegrationKey, string RSAPrivateKey, bool IsDeveloperSandbox, string EmailSubject, string EmailBody, ref int ApiTimeout)
    {
        ApiTimeout *= 1000;

        Config = new DocuSignConfig(UserId, IntegrationKey, RSAPrivateKey, IsDeveloperSandbox);

        APICallInfo apiCallInfo = JWTAuth.GetToken(Config);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiCallInfo.ErrorMessage))
        {
            dynamic envelope = CreateEnvelope(EmailSubject, EmailBody);

            byte[] CRLF = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n");
            byte[] boundary = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("multipartboundary_multipartboundary");
            byte[] hyphens = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("--");

            string uri = apiCallInfo.BaseUri
                    + "/v2.1/accounts/" + apiCallInfo.AccountId + "/envelopes";
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(boundary);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiCallInfo.AccessToken);
            request.Timeout = ApiTimeout < 100000 ? 100000 : ApiTimeout;

            using (var buffer = new BinaryWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                buffer.Write(hyphens);
                buffer.Write(boundary);
                buffer.Write(CRLF);
                buffer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Content-Type: application/json"));
                buffer.Write(CRLF);
                buffer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data"));
                buffer.Write(CRLF);
                buffer.Write(CRLF);

                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelope, Formatting.Indented);
                buffer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json));
                // Loop to add the documents.
                // See section Multipart Form Requests on page https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/requests-and-responses
                foreach (var d in docs)
                {
                    buffer.Write(CRLF);
                    buffer.Write(hyphens);
                    buffer.Write(boundary);
                    buffer.Write(CRLF);
                    buffer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Content-Type:" + d.mime));
                    buffer.Write(CRLF);
                    buffer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"" + d.name + ";documentid=" + d.documentId));
                    buffer.Write(CRLF);
                    buffer.Write(CRLF);
                    buffer.Write(d.bytes);
                }

                // Add closing boundary
                buffer.Write(CRLF);
                buffer.Write(hyphens);
                buffer.Write(boundary);
                buffer.Write(hyphens);
                buffer.Write(CRLF);
                buffer.Flush();
            }

            WebResponse response;
            try
            {
                response = request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            var res = "";

            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    res = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            HttpStatusCode code = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode;
            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
            bool statusOk = code >= HttpStatusCode.OK && code < HttpStatusCode.MultipleChoices;

            if (statusOk)
            {
                return new EnvelopeSummaryCopy()
                {
                    EnvelopeId = obj.envelopeId,
                    Status = obj.status,
                    StatusDateTime = obj.statusDateTime,
                    Uri = obj.uri
                };
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(obj.errorCode + " : " + obj.message);
            }

        }
        else throw new Exception(apiCallInfo.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Error from DocuSign API:

```json
{ 
     "errorCode": "REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE", 
     "message": "The request size of 92875839 bytes exceeded the maximum size of 35651584 bytes."
}
```

Comment: Do you host this API? If you don't then there isn't much you can do. This is a web server limiting the size of files.

Comment: @Liam looking at the error message, the request byte would be 100MB, but he said that he is going to upload 2 20MB files. Though, im not sure if both 20MB files is also counted with the 35MB max limit.

Answer (score 2):

The limit for a single API call is 25mb. As IvanD says, you're trying to upload too much in one API call.

The total document size limit for a single Envelope is larger and should accommodate your two documents. But you'll need to upload them separately.

Or you could create a template that includes the documents and then use the template in your Create Envelope call.

Answer (score 1):

The limit for an envelope is 25MB max (all docs combined), you are trying to upload 2x19MB
Try with only one and see what the result will be